# Java accessing first element of enumeration

Tags: java, enumeration

I want to access elements in an enumeration using the following code:

```
Enumeration<SomeClass> en = someFunctionToRetrieveEnumeration();

while(en.hasMoreElements()){
    String name = en.nextElement().getName();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

The printed output is as follows:

```
name2
```

What should be the output:

```
name1
name2
```

I checked and **en** does contain two elements, why does my code only print the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>`Enumeration<SomeClass> en = someFunctionToRetrieveEnumeration();`</s>

<s>`if(en.hasMoreElements()){`</s>
<s>`do{`</s>
<s>`String name = en.nextElement().getName();`</s>
<s>`System.out.println(name);`</s>
<s>`}while(en.hasMoreElements());`</s>
<s>`}`</s>

Upd:

Seems like function return enumeration with used iterator. Enumeration is an interface. For getting first element you need to know real type of Enumeration and check - if it is possible to iterate it once again(retrieve new iterator)

Comment: This seems just like to be a more complex version of the original code.

Comment: @GáborBakos, Seems like function return enumeration with used iterator

Comment: @msangel, Thank you this was the error. Do you by any chance know if I can reset the iterator?

Comment: @maax, Enumeration is an interface. You need to know real type of Enumeration and check - if it is possible to iterate it once again(retrieve new iterator).